# -1day when calculating time difference. python

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to create an uptime command for the bot e.g "the bot has been online for 10 hours 15 minutes 10 seconds"

It works the way as indented up until it hits 12am, I think it might be to do with the calculation but I'm unsure on why it would add -1day when its formatted in hours minutes seconds.

This is what I have at the moment. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time

folder = r"C:\Users\Ryan Mclaughlin\PycharmProjects\Snappingbot-V2\SnappingbotV2\text files"
filename = "uptime.txt"
fp = os.path.join(folder, filename)

with open(fp, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')) # on startup of bot write the time in a file
file = open(fp)

startup_time = (file.readline())  # reads the startup time

print(startup_time)
time.sleep(10)
time_now = datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # finds time now
print(time_now)

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(time_now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(startup_time,FMT)  # calculates the difference between the startup time and now
print(tdelta)
```

Comment: You will have to include the date for the startup time.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/aFxTGWr.png adding y m d  for startup time returns the date as the year 1900?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Qh5l7Fu.png I added the dates instead of hours and it looks like it works right :)  thanks

Comment: try use dateutil. it has relativedelta type that make it easier to calculate time difference especially when it cross midnight between 2 different days: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

Comment: also, calculating time delta is much easier if you convert the timestamp into epoch, where you will get the delta in seconds, and then you convert it back to hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: Well, you have to include the date _before_ you strip the date with `.time()`

Comment: I thought it had solved the problem but its still showing -1day, I cant find any information on this, how would I include the date before I  strip it?

Comment: every solution I find always has the -1day issue